# VS Setup Project: Process.Start does not open up URLs when ran from within Installer class, but is executed OK from standalone application

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, setup-project, visual-studio-setup-proje

I stumbled upon a problem with which I need some help!

When a process is executed from within a Windows application that runs directly, the call to **Process.Start** opens up the webpage to the default browser.

But when the same Windows application is run through a *Setup Project*, **Process.Start** does not open the URL.

You can download the VS solution from here:
https://pxstorage.blob.core.windows.net/pub/TestSetup.zip

Unfortunately, due to the nature of the problem, it was meaningless to append code snippets.

To replicate the issue:

1. Build the solution
2. *Expected behavior*: Run the **SetupHelper** project and click the Button, and you should see your default browser opening the URL.
3. *Unexpected behavior*: Right-click the **TestSetup** project, click Install and follow the steps. After a popup message, the SetupHelper window will show up, but by clicking the Button, the URL does not open.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Remarks:

- I run it as *Administrator*.
- I already use *UseShellExecute = true*

Comment: There were no errors during my testing, please check if your computer has a firewall or something. Or try it on another machine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when the Windows application is run from a Setup Project, the Process.Start method does not open the URL.

One possible solution would be to use the Process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute property and set it to true. This will cause the process to be started using the ShellExecute method instead of the CreateProcess method.

```
Process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
Process.Start("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: Exactly! That's the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for your time, @LuckyOwl. I already use the UseShellExecute there. Did you try (and see) the code?